# Is there a a shell extension which is like scm_breeze where the output is numbered and you can alias to a file by its number

Tags: shell, ls, git

In `scm_breeze`, output is numbered and you can use the numbers in subsequent commands. For example here I am doing git status to see the changed files and then staging the first file for commit:

```
CodeMirror git/add-quickstart-to-readme*
❯ gs
# On branch: add-quickstart-to-readme  |  [*] => $e*
#
➤ Changes not staged for commit
#
#       modified: [1] lib/codemirror.css
#       modified: [2] package.json
#

CodeMirror git/add-quickstart-to-readme*
❯ ga 1
# Added '/Users/mflander/projects/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css'
#
# On branch: add-quickstart-to-readme  |  [*] => $e*
#
➤ Changes to be committed
#
#       modified: [1] lib/codemirror.css
#
➤ Changes not staged for commit
#
#       modified: [2] package.json
#

CodeMirror git/add-quickstart-to-readme*
```

Is this  based on something more generic that I could use (for example) with the output from `ls` or `find`? Or is it a special thing just in `scm_breeze`?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out by chance that that [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) does this by default (!):

```
~ ❯❯❯ ll
drwx------@  3 mflander  staff   102 17 Mar 14:21 [1]  Applications
drwx------+  3 mflander  staff   102 17 Mar 12:10 [2]  Desktop
drwx------+  3 mflander  staff   102 17 Mar 12:10 [3]  Documents
drwx------+ 10 mflander  staff   340 20 Mar 11:12 [4]  Downloads
drwx------@ 55 mflander  staff  1870 17 Mar 15:23 [5]  Library
drwx------+  3 mflander  staff   102 17 Mar 12:10 [6]  Movies
drwx------+  3 mflander  staff   102 17 Mar 12:10 [7]  Music
drwx------+  3 mflander  staff   102 17 Mar 12:10 [8]  Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  5 mflander  staff   170 17 Mar 12:10 [9]  Public
drwxr-xr-x  23 mflander  staff   782 17 Mar 15:00 [10] anaconda3
drwxr-xr-x   5 mflander  staff   170 20 Mar 09:36 [11] projects
~ ❯❯❯ cd 4
~/Downloads ❯❯❯
```

Answer (score 0):

SCM Breeze also comes with some shell shortcuts for commands such as ls (or ll), and rm: https://github.com/scmbreeze/scm_breeze#ls-shortcuts